How do I fix this error in the Cs50p Cookie jar?
The problem set involves creating a class called jar, and for it to be used as a cookie jar, it can have cookies added to it through deposit, and then cookies removed through withdraw. The program seems to be working as expected when I run it, but I cannot seem to figure out why I am getting this error:
:( Jar's constructor initializes a cookie jar with given capacity
expected exit code 0, not 1
import sys

class Jar:
    def __init__(self, current=0, capacity=12):
        if capacity < 1:
            raise ValueError("cannot be negative cookies")
        self._capacity = capacity


        if current < 0 or current > self.capacity:
            raise ValueError("Invalid initial number of cookies")
        self.current = current         



    def __str__(self):
        return "" * self.current

    def deposit(self, n):
        jar_total = self.current + n
        if jar_total > self.capacity:
            raise ValueError ("too many cookies")
        self.current = jar_total

    def withdraw(self, n):
        jar_total = self.current - n
        if jar_total < 0:
            raise  ValueError ("not enough cookies")
        self.current = jar_total

    @property
    def capacity(self):
        return self._capacity

    @property
    def size(self):
        return self.current
    

def main():
    my_jar = Jar()
    while True:
        user_action = input("deposit of withdraw? (or exit to quit:) ").strip().lower()
        if user_action == "exit":
            print("Goodbye")
            break

        if user_action in ["deposit", "withdraw"]:
            try:
                n = int(input("how many cookies?: "))
                if user_action == "deposit":
                    my_jar.deposit(n)
                else:
                    my_jar.withdraw(n)
                print(f"current number of cookies in the jar: {my_jar.size}")
                print(my_jar)
            except ValueError as e:
                print(f"error:{e}")
        else:
            print("options are: deposit, withdraw or exit ya dam fool!")
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()

from jar import Jar

def test_init():
    jar = Jar()
    assert jar.current == 0
    assert jar.capacity == 12
    jar = Jar(5, 10)
    assert jar.current == 5
    assert jar.capacity == 10

def test_str():
    jar = Jar()
    assert str(jar) == ""
    jar.deposit(1)
    assert str(jar) == ""
    jar.deposit(11)
    assert str(jar) == ""

def test_deposit():
    jar = Jar()
    assert str(jar) == ""
    jar.deposit(1)
    assert str(jar) == ""
    jar.deposit(5)
    assert str(jar) == ""
    jar = Jar(0, 6)
    jar.deposit(6)
    assert jar.size == 6

def test_withdraw():
    jar = Jar(12)
    assert str(jar) == ""
    jar.withdraw(5)
    assert str(jar) == ""
    jar.withdraw(7)
    assert str(jar) == ""


I've tried changing a few things around, but I cannot seem to remove this error. Where would I be looking?

Read the problem specification closely. There are 3 problems with your __init__ method 1) You changed the method signature 2) A ValueError should be raised if capacity is not a  non-negative int. 3) The cookie jar should always be initialized with 0 cookies in it.

Please always provide the error message you get. Error messages are a holy present.

@oskar  He did post the "error message".  It's the failed result from the CS50 Autograder program that starts with the :(

Thank you, I actually haven't identified this as an error. But where is this raised?

@oskar They are doing this problem set from the Harvard CS50 Python  course.  Problem sets for the course are submitted to an autograder program called check50.  Check50 is returning a failure for the test Jar's constructor initializes a cookie jar with given capacity with a result of  expected exit code 0, not 1  I could give the poster a completion solution, but that would violate the academy honesty rules for the course.  The problem is that their solution does not meet the problem specifications, as I noted in my first comment.
